# GAE / java11 / Datastore / DataNucleus getting runtime exception: org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidMemberMetaDataException

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey, java-11, datanucleus

So I am in the process of migrating a Java8-based app to a Java11-based app. While on Java8, the app was relaying on bundled legacy services (Jersey 2.25) and GAE provided a roadmap for seamlessly moving to Java11 by effecting a few changes in a couple of XML files. I made those changes as per "If your app is using the legacy bundled services, App Engine deploys it using Jetty in the same way as in the Java 8 runtime." [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/standard/migrate-to-second-gen/java-differences) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/services/access#v17-and-earlier).

After having made those changes, I can see Java11 on the GAE console. I do not use any Java11-specific features in my code so I am happy with the Java8 codebase, for now.

However, when the app performs a database I/O on an Entity that has an attribute defined as `List<MyCustomType>`, I get this exception....

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Class "com.applix.cliniX.entities.Estb" field "com.applix.cliniX.entities.Estb" : declared as a reference type (interface/Object) but no implementation classes of "java.util.List" have been found!
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.SizeLimitHandler.handle(SizeLimitHandler.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:269)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:100)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:184)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchServletRequest(RequestRunner.java:262)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchRequest(RequestRunner.java:227)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.run(RequestRunner.java:193)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Class "com.applix.cliniX.entities.Estb" field "com.applix.cliniX.entities.Estb" : declared as a reference type (interface/Object) but no implementation classes of "java.util.List" have been found!
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:302)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getSingleResult(JPAQuery.java:253)
    at com.applix.cliniX.serverApp.dao.DaoEstb.getEstbByName(DaoEstb.java:1096)
    at com.applix.cliniX.serverApp.controller.StartupController.getLatestVersionDeployDate(StartupController.java:290)
    at com.applix.cliniX.serverApp.controller.StartupController.newVersionDeployed(StartupController.java:304)
    at com.applix.cliniX.serverApp.controller.StartupController.loadCache(StartupController.java:207)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidMemberMetaDataException: Class "com.applix.cliniX.entities.Estb" field "com.applix.cliniX.entities.Estb" : declared as a reference type (interface/Object) but no implementation classes of "java.util.List" have been found!
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataUtils.getImplementationNamesForReferenceField(MetaDataUtils.java:549)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.ReferenceMapping.createPerImplementationColumnsForReferenceField(ReferenceMapping.java:288)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.ReferenceMapping.prepareDatastoreMapping(ReferenceMapping.java:210)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.ReferenceMapping.initialize(ReferenceMapping.java:106)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.InterfaceMapping.initialize(InterfaceMapping.java:52)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.MappingFactory.createMapping(MappingFactory.java:97)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.AbstractMappingManager.getMapping(AbstractMappingManager.java:263)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.mapping.DatastoreTable.addFieldMapping(DatastoreTable.java:491)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.mapping.DatastoreTable.initializeNonPK(DatastoreTable.java:436)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.mapping.DatastoreTable.buildMapping(DatastoreTable.java:374)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager.buildStoreData(DatastoreManager.java:439)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager.newStoreData(DatastoreManager.java:403)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.addClasses(AbstractStoreManager.java:1183)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.addClass(AbstractStoreManager.java:1157)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mapped.MappedStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(MappedStoreManager.java:407)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager.getDatastoreClass(DatastoreManager.java:544)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery.compile(DatastoreQuery.java:234)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery.performExecute(JPQLQuery.java:170)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1789)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1693)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getSingleResult(JPAQuery.java:232)
```

Following are the versions that I was using (Java8) and using even now (Java11):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<!--             <version>5.0.2</version>       -->
                <version>4.0.0-release</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JPA</api>
                    <persistenceUnitName>transactions-optional</persistenceUnitName>
                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I believe I am adhering to the compatibility shown [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/datanucleus-appengine/wikis/Compatibility.wiki).
To reiterate, the above used to work as expected when I was using the earlier GAE configuration.

So I am unable to determine if this is a Java11 issue or a Jersey2.25 issue or a DataNucleus3.11 issue or a datanucleus-appengine issue or a combination thereof. More importantly, how does one solve this issue? Are there some other versions of the above that I need to use for Java11? The alternative that I am contemplating right now is to plug out DataNucleus and perform database I/O using native API exposed by GAE Datastore thereby eliminating one (rather important) dependency.

Modified:
As per this [link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Datanucleus-appengine-plugin-2-1-2-JAVA-17-migration/m-p/526547), it seems that moving away from DataNucleus is the only option.
Any opinions?

Comment: No, It looks like removing `DataNucleus` is the better option and using `Java Objectify` as suggested in this [Link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Datanucleus-appengine-plugin-2-1-2-JAVA-17-migration/m-p/526547) you shared. You may also raise [Feature request](http://www.issuetracker.google.com/) explaining your problem and requesting this functionality.

Comment: @Sandeep Vokkareni....Thanks a lot for your response. I kept thinking I am doing something radically incorrect until I read your response. Now on the issue of replacing DataNucleus with "something else", there are2 broad options: use low-level APIs provided by GAE datastore,, or, use Objectify. Well, a few months/years down the line, I do not want to find my self in the same situation that I am in right now, i.e., debate about replacing Objectify with something else. So I guess I will prefer to go with the so-called low-level GAE native datastore APIs. I will put in the feature request.

Comment: Even if a put a feature request and even if it gets honored, it will be too late because I will have moved away from DN!!!!

Comment: The feature request link is broken. Please re-post.

Comment: Yes, As the Google engineering team will work on it and it takes time to check the possibility of the required functionality and there is no ETA. As you are concerned about replacing `Objectify` with something else in future,  it's better to go with low-level APIs provided by GAE datastore. And the [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com) link is here.